# Redux Observable and async fetch call

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have an epic like this

```
const getProjectsEpic = action$ => 
  action$.ofType(state.GET_PROJECTS_REQUEST)
         .switchMap(action =>  fetchService())
         .map(res => actions.getProjectsRequestSuccess(res))
         .catch((error) => actions.getProjectsRequestFailure(error));
```

And inside `fetchService` I got

```
export async function fetchService() {
  let response = await fetch('http://apiendpoint');
  return (validateStatusCode(response)) ? response.json() : new Error(response.statusText); 
}
```

Trying to find out what I'm doing wrong but the console is throwing me:

```
runtime.js?c1c3:288 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?c1c3:288)
at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
at step (asyncToGenerator.js?6185:17)
at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?6185:35)
```

Can someone explain it to me and how to debug better having a similar issue in future.

Answer (score 1):

From here [learnRxJs - switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html),

the project function should return an observable, so I'd try wrapping the return values of your `fetchService` function.

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
...
export async function fetchService() {
  let response = await fetch('http://apiendpoint');
  return (validateStatusCode(response)) 
    ? of(response.json()) 
    : of(new Error(response.statusText)); 
}
```

or instead perhaps

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
...
const getProjectsEpic = action$ => 
  action$.ofType(state.GET_PROJECTS_REQUEST)
         .switchMap(action => of(fetchService()))
         .map(res => actions.getProjectsRequestSuccess(res))
         .catch((error) => actions.getProjectsRequestFailure(error));
```